# Django how to remove the ForeignKey in the template

Tags: django

I want to remove ForeignKey in the forms and in the template and it generates it automaticallyenter code here

the models and the forms are there:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
class PostProduit(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categorie = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    prix_en_FCFA = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Whatsapp = models.BooleanField(max_length=255)
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="image/")
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="image/", null=True, blank=True)
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="image/", null=True, blank=True)
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="image/", null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} ===> {self.titre}"

class PostProduitForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PostProduit
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the fields you want to add in the form in your `fields` variable like so:

```py
fields = ['titre', 'categorie', 'description', ...]
```

You can always refer to the [Official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#iterating-relationship-choices) for more information.

Comment: but how I can add the automatic ForeignKey in the html file without the user seeing it

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by that. Do you mean that you want to have access to it in the template without it being in the form?